# Why are all my if statements firing at once? (Java)

Tags: java, applet

I have a problem with my java applet assignment. For some reason that I cannot figure out, whenever I check a checkbox all of my if statements fire at once. The program is supposed to update the Total Price and notify the user each time a box is pressed. We must use checkbox and not radio buttons or JCheckBox and the program must be written as an applet. Here is a link to my code.

```
// Classes
import java.awt.*;                                                                                              
import java.applet.*;                                                                                           
import java.awt.event.*;                                                                                         


@SuppressWarnings("serial")                                                                                     
public class ReasonableComputersChristiansen extends Applet implements ItemListener                             
{
// Variables
        Image logo;                                                                                              
        double basePrice;                                                                                       

        Label companyLabel = new Label("Reasonable Computers");                                                 
        Label instructionLabel = new Label("Please select your desired peripherals from the list below");       
        Label outputLabel = new Label("TOTAL PRICE: ");                                                         

        Checkbox printerBox = new Checkbox("Ink Waster 9000");                                                  
        Checkbox monitorBox = new Checkbox("EvilCorp Monitor");                                                 
        Checkbox keyboardBox = new Checkbox("Clickity-Clackity Keyboard");                                      
        Checkbox mouseBox = new Checkbox("Worst-Aim Laser Gaming Mouse");                                       
        Checkbox joystickBox = new Checkbox("Crash and Burn X-2 Joystick");                                     
        Checkbox webcamBox = new Checkbox("Not-So-Anonymous Webcam");                                           


// Components
    public void init()                                                                                          
        {
        add(companyLabel);                                                                                      
        add(instructionLabel);                                                                                  
        add(printerBox);                                                                                        
        printerBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                       
        add(monitorBox);                                                                                        
        monitorBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                       
        add(keyboardBox);                                                                                       
        keyboardBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                      
        add(mouseBox);                                                                                          
        mouseBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                         
        add(joystickBox);                                                                                       
        joystickBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                      
        add(webcamBox);                                                                                         
        webcamBox.addItemListener(this);                                                                        
        add(outputLabel);                                                                                       
        logo = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "logo.gif");                                                         
        }

// Actions
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)                                                                   
        {
        basePrice = 575.00;                                                                                     

        if (printerBox.getState());                                                                             
            {
            basePrice += 69.99;                                                                                 
            System.out.println("Printer added!");                                                               
            }
        if (monitorBox.getState());                                                                             
            {
            basePrice += 125.49;                                                                                
            System.out.println("Monitor added!");                                                               
            }
        if (keyboardBox.getState());                                                                            
            {
            basePrice += 55.59;                                                                                 
            System.out.println("Keyboard added!");                                                              
            }
        if (mouseBox.getState());                                                                               
            {
            basePrice += 19.99;                                                                                 
            System.out.println("Mouse added!");                                                                 
            }
        if (joystickBox.getState());                                                                            
            {
            basePrice += 224.97;                                                                                
            System.out.println("Joystick added!");                                                              
            }
        if (webcamBox.getState());                                                                              
            {
            basePrice += 99.19;                                                                                 
            System.out.println("Webcam added!");                                                                
            }
        }
// Output
    public void output()                                                                                        
        {
            outputLabel.setText("TOTAL PRICE: $" + (basePrice));                                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your `;`s

Answer (score 1):

You should not have semicolons after your `if` statements.

**Corrected Code:**

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)                                                                   
    {
    basePrice = 575.00;                                                                                     

    if (printerBox.getState())                                                                            
        {
        basePrice += 69.99;                                                                                 
        System.out.println("Printer added!");                                                               
        }
    if (monitorBox.getState())                                                                            
        {
        basePrice += 125.49;                                                                                
        System.out.println("Monitor added!");                                                               
        }
    if (keyboardBox.getState())                                                                         
        {
        basePrice += 55.59;                                                                                 
        System.out.println("Keyboard added!");                                                              
        }
    if (mouseBox.getState())                                                                            
        {
        basePrice += 19.99;                                                                                
        System.out.println("Mouse added!");                                                                 
        }
    if (joystickBox.getState())                                                                         
        {
        basePrice += 224.97;                                                                                
        System.out.println("Joystick added!");                                                              
        }
    if (webcamBox.getState())                                                                            
        {
        basePrice += 99.19;                                                                                 
        System.out.println("Webcam added!");                                                                
        }
    }
```

The semicolons end your `if` statements so they don't actually affect what code runs.

**Hold on, but wouldn't the curly braces result in syntax errors, then?**

Nope.  As far as Java's concerned, you can use curly braces just for organization and they don't throw syntax errors.  In most cases **should** you do that?  No.  But can you do it?  Technically, yes.

*(the caveat to "in most cases" is when you need to intentionally put variables in a specific scope, as Andy Turner mentioned)*

Comment: "Should you do that? No." Except for when you want to enclose variables in a tight scope.

Comment: Oh, plain curly braces create a new scope?  That's awesome.  I didn't realize that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent about 4 hours searching the web for this answer haha!

Comment: No problem!  I cannot even tell you how many times I've dealt with similar issues that I just. can't. solve.

Comment: "I cannot even tell you how many times I've dealt with similar issues" Then improve your compiler tooling. [Errorprone would catch this as a compiler error](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/EmptyIf).

Comment: Thanks, @AndyTurner, I'll look into that!